# MongoDB aggregate multiple group $sum per wildcard key

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

I have 1 collection with the following documents

```
{
  _id: '1234',
  __extract: {
     flavor: 'apple',
     color: 'green'
  }
}

{
  _id: '1235',
  __extract: {
     flavor: 'apple',
     color: 'green'
  }
}

{
  _id: '1236',
  __extract: {
     flavor: 'mint',
     color: 'green'
  }
}

{
  _id: '1237',
  __extract: {
     flavor: 'mint',
     color: 'blue'
  }
}

{
  _id: '1238',
  __extract: {
     flavor: 'mint',
     color: 'blue'
  }
}
```

What I expect from my aggregation is the following result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 'flavor',
   results: [
     {
       _id: 'apple',
       count: 2
     },
     {
       _id: 'mint',
       count: 3
     },
   ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'color',
   results: [
     {
       _id: 'green',
       count: 3
     },
     {
       _id: 'blue',
       count: 2
     },
   ]
  },
]
```

All I got until now is group by flavor, but I don't even have 'flavor' in the result, I only have the different flavors and the different counts, I group by `$__extract.flavor` and have a field named count which uses `$sum: 1` like so:

```
$group:
    _id: '$__index.flavor'
    count:
      $sum: 1
```

Is it possible without doing multiple aggregate calls?

Comment: You should use map reduce or used two different aggregation one for group by  `flavor` and second for group by `color`.

Comment: every aggregate takes like 4000 ms and there could be many aggregates, i wouldnt prefer that, also mapReduce takes a lot of time and memory, it already crashed my aws instance